# Como abrir um executável empacotado no projeto?

Tags: java, arquivo

Estou executando um programa da seguinte forma:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\meuprograma.exe");
```

No qual funciona normalmente. Mas gostaria de empacotar os arquivos (o executável e mais alguns) dentro do meu projeto para o usuário não precisar ficar manipulando os arquivos. Além do mais, o arquivo é importante somente no momento de execução, então não tem necessidade de eu criar um diretório para "instalar" os arquivos necessários (a menos que essa seja a única solução, claro). Criei uma estrutura semelhante a essa:

```
src
 |__ br.foo.files
 |__ br.foo.main
```

Supondo que minha classe que chamará o executável esteja dentro do pacote `main`, como faço para executar um arquivo dentro do pacote `files`? Tentei:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("files/meuprograma.exe");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./files/meuprograma.exe");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/files/meuprograma.exe");
```

No qual todos geraram a seguinte exceção:

> Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Cannot run program
>   "files/meuprograma.exe": CreateProcess error=2, O sistema não pode
>   encontrar o arquivo especificado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
File home = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
File file2 = new File(home, "files/meuprograma.exe");
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(file2.getPath());
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/IO/GetCurrentDir.java).

[Documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html).

Dá para fazer de forma mais simples concatenando as *strings* sem criar o *path* real, mas esta é a forma mais correta.

Comment: Em tese não precisa. Sei lá se não tem alguma coisa específica do NetBeans criando algum problema. O que eu fiz essencialmente é pegar o diretório onde a aplicação está sendo executada. Se não for isto que deseja eu não saberia dizer mais nada. Me avise para eu remover a resposta.

Comment: Gostaria de saber qual é o erro aqui para ter um -1?

Comment: what? Não tem erro, creio eu.

Comment: @rrnan na verdade alguém saiu distribuindo -1 em coisas minhas.